# How can I quit from multiple-cursor mode by ESC

Tags: key-bindings, multiple-cursors

I want to bind `ESC` to quit from multiple-cursor mode.

This code doesn't work:

```
(define-key mc/keymap (kbd "<ESC>") 'mc/keyboard-quit)
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by changing `<ESC>` to `<escape>`:

```
(define-key mc/keymap (kbd "<escape>") 'mc/keyboard-quit))
```

EDIT:
Also need to check in `.mc-lists.el` `keyboard-escape-quit` should be 
in

```
(setq mc / cmds-to-run-for-all
      '(
        keyboard-escape-quit))
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `define-key` you should try using the snippet below:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'multiple-cursors-core
  (define-key mc/keymap (kbd "<ESC>") 'mc/keyboard-quit))
```

so that the `mc/keymap` is defined by the file `multiple-cursors-core.el/elc` *before* a new keyboard shortcut is added thereto.

If the solution above does not work you can assign temporarily a custom keybind except ESC in order not to break other commands with the snippet below

```
(global-set-key (kbd "some keybind") 'mc/keyboard-quit)
```

Comment: Please explain this one-liner, saying how it answers the questino.

Comment: `define-key` is a function that sets a keybind for a specifc mode.

`global-set-key` is a wrapper of `define-key` that sets this keybind for every mode.

If @Pfedj insists on using `define-key` he may need wrapping it like this 

`(with-eval-after-load 'multiple-cursors
  (define-key mc/keymap ...)`

Comment: Your comment *is* the correct answer; i.e., `(with-eval-after-load 'multiple-cursors (define-key mc/keymap ...))`.  The `global-set-key` should not be used here.  The `mc/keymap` needs to be defined *before* it can be modified by adding additional keys or changing an existing.

Comment: Not sure this is a good idea, `ESC` is a prefix key equivalent to `M-`, so this will break all `M-` bindings.

Comment: Well at least he  can use temporarily the `global-set-key` option if the solution `(with-eval-after-load 'multiple-cursors (define-key mc/keymap ...))` does not work.

Comment: APART from comments here trying to help refine your answer: Please update the answer itself so that it *explains* the code you provide. A one-liner code answer risks being deleted as low quality. And comments can be removed at any time - put all answer info into your answer, please.

Comment: When `multiple-cursors` is off / inactive, there is no conceivable reason why a user would ever want to call `mc/keyboard-quit` in a global capacity.  That is why, `global-set-key` is the *wrong* answer.

Comment: @GeorgeXanthakis Thank for you participation. Unfortunately `(with-eval-after-load 'multiple-cursors (define-key mc/keymap ...))` doesn't work in regard to my issue.

Comment: @Pfedj @George Xanthakis -- My apologies for not specifying that it should have been `multiple-cursors-core` instead of `multiple-cursors`.  I have fixed the first part of the answer and also verified it works using Emacs 26 and no user configuration other than the snippet:  `(with-eval-after-load 'multiple-cursors-core (define-key mc/keymap (kbd "<ESC>") 'mc/keyboard-quit))`.

Comment: OK appreciate it @lawlist.